# nordvpn: command not found on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I have downloaded .deb package of nordvpn from their website and I have installed it with:

```
sudo apt install <nordvpn-package-name.deb>
```

it installed without any error. But when I type nordvpn in terminal it says command not found and if i try to reinstall .deb package it says nordvpn is already installed.

Also there is no GUI application for nordvpn.

Comment: This is probably more of a question for NordVPN than for this forum...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some reason .deb package is not working. I resolved this issue by following these steps:

```
cd Downloads/
wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

And then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nordvpn
```

Now

```
nordvpn connect
```

works!

Comment: I Followed yours steps
After nordvpn connect This was the message Whoops! /run/nordvpn/nordvpnd.sock not found. What should I do next

Comment: Run this cmd: 
"sudo usermod -aG nordvpn $USER"
  without the quotes, then restart your computer

Comment: still not works by .deb in Ubuntu 22.04